# IdentityDbContext, no constructor that takes one argument microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework 3.0.0-rc1-final

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity

IdentityDbContext has only constructor that takes 0 arguments in the version specified in the title discription. I am missing a constructor that takes connection string.

Is it in some kind of specific extension?

Comment: What code throws the error? Does your app context inherit from IdentityDbContext?